# What if an object passed into std::swap throws an exception during swapping?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, standards, swap

The C++ standard guarantees that `std::swap` will throw no exception. However, what if an object to swap throws an exception during swapping? Next, how should the caller find an exception has happened? and what measures should the caller take?

PS: It is very common that a constructor throws an exception.

```
struct A
{
    A(const A&)
    {
        throw 1;
    }

    A& operator =(const A&)
    {
        throw 2;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a1, a2;
    std::swap(a1, a2); // An exception happened, but the caller doesn't know.
    // How to do here ???
}
```

Comment: 10 lashes for A's author for not providing a non-throwing `swap(A, A)` overload

Comment: @rhalbersma: not that providing an overload would help, since the questioner's code fully-qualifies the call `std::swap`.

Comment: @SteveJessop see my answer why indeed that would be much better.

Comment: "*It is very common that a constructor throws an exception.*" It is *not* very common for a copy constructor to throw an exception (outside of memory allocation errors).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> The C++ standard guarantees that std::swap will throw no exception.

No, it doesn't. See 20.2.2 or [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap). There are two noexcept specifications for the two `std::swap` overloads:

```
template<class T> void swap(T& a, T& b)
noexcept(noexcept(
    std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
    std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value
))

template<class T, size_t N>
void swap(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N])    
noexcept(noexcept(swap(*a, *b)))
```

When these conditions aren't satisfied, `std::swap` can throw and you can catch it.

---

In case of the class you have presented, the predicates `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` and `std::is_nothrow_move_assignable` are false, so the instantiation `std::swap<A>` doesn't have the no-throw guarantee. It's perfectly legal to catch exceptions from this swap.

Comment: how can these conditions not be satisfied? there are no other overloads without a `noexcept` specification. You cannot catch an exception thrown from within `std::swap`

Comment: swap has a conditional `noexcept` specification. It is `noexcept` when instantiated with a type for which move construction and move assignment are `noexcept`. Otherwise it can throw anything.

Comment: @rhalbersma cppreference has some nice descriptions how [the `noexpect` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) and [the `noexpect` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) work, please read up

Answer (score 10):

The standard does not generally guarantee that swap doesn't throw.

From 20.2.2/1:

> template void swap(T& a, T& b) noexcept(*see below*);
>
> Remark: The expression inside noexcept is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
>  is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value
> ```