# How is std::atomic<T>::operator= implemented for immutable types?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, stdatomic, exception-safety

I've learned that one way to communicate between threads is to share some atomic data structure. For example:

```
struct Point {
    int const x, y;
};

std::atomic<Point> some_point_in_shared_memory{Point{0, 0}};
```

Despite `Point::operator=(Point const &)` being deleted, there seems to be [no problem](https://godbolt.org/z/dbd7fx) calling the assignment operator for `std::atomic<Point>` as follows:

```
some_point_in_shared_memory = Point{1, 2};
```

How can this operation be implemented?

One solution I might think about is using `placement new` to construct a new object on top of the old one, but apparently [it is not exception safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177884/can-i-use-placement-newthis-in-operator). Or is it okay because `Point` is trivially-copyable?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "there seems to be no problem?" Does your code compile? If so, your standard library has a bug, since `std::atomic<T>` requires `T` to be trivially copyable

Comment: gcc and clang accept this. MSVC and ICC don't.

Comment: @alterigel see [this](https://godbolt.org/z/1WzY8f). Also edited link into *no problem*. Also, `Point` is trivially-copyable.

Comment: Where do you delete `Point::operator=(Point const &)`?  You declared `Point` as a plain struct so this doesn't look like a [mcve].  Also, your title still says "immutable".  Is that really what you meant?

Comment: Also, compile with optimization enabled to simplify the asm output to just the expected qword seq-cst store, implemented with `xchg` for its implicit `lock` behaviour.  https://godbolt.org/z/sdTEv9

Comment: @PeterCordes `Point` is an immutable type, since the integers `x` and `y` are constant, and for this reason the assignment operator is implicitly deleted. The example is reproducable, as you noticed yourself. And it's nice to see that this is potimized out to a single `xchg` command, but it does not have anything to do with the original question.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't notice the `const` in the declaration.

Comment: The simple A is that atomic ops are always implemented in term of access to bits not high level objects; that's why `std::atomic<std::string>` was never expected to work when it passed compilation. You can call `memcpy` on `struct Point` in term of types and const correctness (the target object of type `struct Point` is non const) but the behavior may or may not be defined depending on the interpretation of the words of each std.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic):

> The primary std::atomic template may be instantiated with any
> TriviallyCopyable type T satisfying both CopyConstructible and
> CopyAssignable. The program is ill-formed if any of following values
> is false:
>
> ```
> std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value
> std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value
> std::is_move_constructible<T>::value
> std::is_copy_assignable<T>::value
> std::is_move_assignable<T>::value
> ```

Your `T` is not CopyAssignable, and this line

```
some_point_in_shared_memory = Point{1, 2};
```

is ill-formed. There should be a compiler error. Unfortunately I didn't get GCC to emit an error or warning (`-pedantic -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Werror=pedantic` no effect).

Comment: We do need concepts

Comment: @BennyK I dont get what you are saying. If `Point` is immutable then very likely you need no `std::atomic<Point>` because already `Point` can only be read not written