# Using copy constructor in assignment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

Is it against style guidelines to use the copy-constructor in the assignment operator? I.e.:

```
const Obj & Obj::operator=(const Obj & source)
{
    if (this == &source)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    // deep copy using copy-constructor
    Obj * copy = new Obj(source);

    // deallocate memory
    this->~Obj();

    // modify object
    *this = *copy;

    return *copy;
}
```

Assuming that the copy-constructor performs a deep copy on the object.

---

EDIT:

My code is extremely erroneous, as commenters have pointed out.

As for the overall conceptual question: as WhozCraig suggested, the copy/swap idiom seems to be the way to go: [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: your assignment operator is against style because it doesn't do an assignment. The object you are assigning to will not even be valid after the assignment.

Comment: Its beyond against style, its utterly pointless and leaves `*this` in a deconstructed state, but still (potentially) allocated. The result will be a double-destructed object, which is *bad*. If you want to use the copy-ctor in assignment, [**read about the copy/swap idiom**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: Oops, my bad. I left out the line to modify the object. But sure, suppose assignment occurred -- my question was if the overall concept was against coding guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, WhozCraig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the copy/swap idiom on your example in a nutshell:

```
#include <algorithm>

class Obj
{
    int *p;
    void swap(Obj& left, Obj& right);

public:
    Obj(int x = 0) : p(new int(x)) {}
    Obj(const Obj& s);
    Obj& operator = (const Obj& s);
    ~Obj() { delete p; }
};

Obj::Obj(const Obj& source) : p(new int(*source.p))
{}

void Obj::swap(Obj& left, Obj& right)
{
    std::swap(left.p, right.p);
}

Obj & Obj::operator=(const Obj & source)
{
    Obj temp(source);
    swap(*this, temp);
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Obj o1(5);
    Obj o2(o1);
    Obj o3(10);
    o1 = o3;
}
```

To see how it works, I purposefully created a member that is a pointer to dynamically allocated memory (this would be problematic if there were no user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator).

If you focus on the assignment operator, it calls the `Obj` copy constructor to construct a temporary object.  Then the `Obj`-specific `swap` is called that swaps the individual members.  Now, the magic is in the `temp` object after the `swap` is called.

When the destructor of `temp` is called, it will call `delete` on the pointer value that `this` used to have, but was swapped out with the `temp` pointer.  So when `temp` goes out of scope, it cleaned up the memory allocated by the "old" pointer.

Also, note that during assignment, if `new` throws an exception during the creation of the temporary object, the assignment will throw an exception before any members of `this` become changed.  This prevents the object from having members that may be corrupted due to having them changed inadvertently.

Now, a previous answer was given that uses the often-used "shared code" approach to copy assignment.  Here is a full example of this method, and an explanation of why it has issues:

```
class Obj
{
    int *p;
    void CopyMe(const Obj& source);

public:
    Obj(int x = 0) : p(new int(x)) {}
    Obj(const Obj& s);
    Obj& operator = (const Obj& s);
    ~Obj() { delete p; }
};

void Obj::CopyMe(const Obj& source)
{
    delete p;
    p = new int(*source.p);
}

Obj::Obj(const Obj& source) : p(0)
{
   CopyMe(source);
}

Obj & Obj::operator=(const Obj & source)
{
    if ( this != &source )
        CopyMe(source);
    return *this;
}
```

So you would say "what's wrong with this?"  Well, the thing that's wrong is that `CopyMe`'s first thing it does is call `delete p;`.  Then the next question you'll ask is "So what?  Isn't that what we're supposed to do, delete the old memory?"

The issue with this is that there is a potential for the subsequent call to `new` to fail.  So what we did was destroy our data before we even know that the new data will be available.  If `new` now throws an exception, we've messed up our object.

Yes, you can fix it easily by creating a temporary pointer, allocating, and at the end, assign the temp pointer to `p`.  But many times this can be forgotten, and code such as above remains in the codebase forever, even though it has a potential corruption bug.

To illustrate, here is the fix for the `CopyMe`:

```
void Obj::CopyMe(const Obj& source)  
{
    int *pTemp = new int(*source.p);
    delete p;
    p = pTemp;
}
```

But again, you will see tons of code that use the "shared code" method that has this potential bug and not mention a word about the exception issue.

Comment: Note that it changes slightly for C++11: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a82499122a5df2ab

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do doesn't work.  You seem to be thinking that the object the assignment operator returns becomes the new "this", but that is not the case.
You have not modified the object, just destroyed it.

```
Obj a;
Obj b;
a = b; // a has been destroyed
       // and you've leaked a new Obj.
// At the end of the scope, it will try to destroy `a` again, which
// is undefined behavior.
```

It is possible to implement an assignment operator by using placement `new`, but it is a fragile solution, and not generally recommended:

```
const Obj & Obj::operator=(const Obj & source)
{
    if (this == &source)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    this->~Obj();

    new (this) Obj(source);

    return *this;
}
```

This causes problems if exceptions are possible during construction and it potentially causes problems with derived classes.

Comment: Thanks, Vaughn, I accidentally left a line out. Could you provide insight as to whether the overall concept is against convention? I'm checking out the copy/swap idiom, as WhozCraig suggested. If you have any other insight, please let me know.

Comment: @dailgez004: with the new line `*this = *obj`, you are now just causing an infinite recursion, by using the assignment operator to implement itself.

Comment: @dailgez004 - `whether the overall concept is against convention` In all the material that you've read, where have you seen code where the user explicitly calls the destructor? `this->~Obj();`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I had written my own code based on my beginner intuition, and wanted to ensure it was proper. Which are you suggesting, that my code is unconventional or that it's erroneous?

Comment: @dailgez004 - When learning C++, don't use "beginner intutition".  Use well-known material such as books and sites that have been peer-reviewed.  Otherwise you end up writing code that, if not conventional, just plain wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It totally makes sense to share code between copy constructor and assigmnet operator because they often do the same operations (copying object passed as parameter attributes to this).

Personnaly, I often do it by smartly coding my assignment operator and then calling it from the copy constructor:

```
Obj::Obj(const Obj & source)
{
    Obj::operator=( source );
}

const Obj& Obj::operator=(const Obj& source)
{
    if (this != &source)
    {
        // copy source attribtes to this.
    }    
    return *this;
}
```

It works if you write the `operator=` correctly. **As commented, one may recommend to have a swap function used by both**: [Copy constructor and = operator overload in C++: is a common function possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734628/copy-constructor-and-operator-overload-in-c-is-a-common-function-possible/1734640#1734640)

Anyway, your idea to share code between both functions was good, but the way you implemented it does not. work for sure..it has many problems and does not do what you mean to. It calls recursively the operator=. Moreover, you should never explictely call destructor functions as you did (`this->~Obj();`).

Comment: Aha! Thanks, I wasn't aware this was the convention. This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Your are welcome. Then please vote up and confirm it's the right answer ;-)

Comment: @dailgez004 this isn't the convention. It may not even work. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734628/copy-constructor-and-operator-overload-in-c-is-a-common-function-possible/1734640#1734640) for further discussion

Comment: @jpo89 this is not the general way to do it, and this is a bad idea

Comment: @Matt McNabb. Thanks, I learned something today. I'll update my post. But downvoting was rude.....if code is written correctly, my proposition works well (I did it for hundred of classes with no issue)

Comment: @jpo38 voting is about the quality of the post content, not the author's personality

Comment: No problem. I just did not feel the post quality was so bad. It works well if you write the assignment operator correctly. But as you're not the only one to vote down....I probably deserve it ;-)

Comment: @jpo38 - Your example may work for hundreds of classes, but the issue of exception safety was not brought up at all in your version.  I have seen many examples coded the way you wrote, and invariably they're coded incorrectly w.r.t exception safety (even though the code looks like it is flawless).  The copy/swap alleviates the problem of exception safety.