# Default/Copy/Move constructor correctness.

Tags: c++, memory, copy-constructor

I have not worked with copy constructors/move constructors, and am trying to include them in a sparse matrix and vector library I am writing. I thought everything was peachy, everything was working well, operator overloading seemed to be successful, etc. Then I moved on to writing some basic iterative methods and was hit with debilitating memory errors. I believe it has to do with my constructors and assignment operators shown below:

```
/* Default constructor. */
CSC_Vector::CSC_Vector()
{
    m_length  = 0.;
    m_values = new double[0];
}

/* Constructor for vector of given input length. Initializes to 0 default. */
/* Input: unsigned int - length                                            */
CSC_Vector::CSC_Vector(const unsigned int & length)
{
    m_length = length;
    m_values = new double[length]();
}

/* Copy constructor. */
CSC_Vector::CSC_Vector(const CSC_Vector & vec) 
{
    // Copy vector length and values. 
    m_length = vec.m_length;
    m_values = new double[m_length];
    for(int i=0; i<m_length; i++) {
        m_values[i] = vec(i);
    }
}

/* Move constructor. */
CSC_Vector::CSC_Vector(CSC_Vector && vec) 
{
    // Move vector length and values to current object.
    m_values = vec.m_values;
    m_length = vec.m_length;
    vec.m_values = nullptr;
    vec.m_length = 0;   
}

/* Copy assignment operator. */
CSC_Vector& operator=(const CSC_Vector & vec) {
    cout << "Copy assign vector." << endl;
    delete [] m_values; 
    m_length = vec.m_length;
    m_values = new double[vec.m_length];
    for(int i=0; i<m_length; i++) {
        m_values[i] = vec(i);
    }
    return *this;
};
/* Move assignment operator. */
CSC_Vector& operator=(CSC_Vector && vec) {
    cout << "Move assign vector." << endl;
    delete [] m_values;
    m_length     = vec.m_length;
    m_values     = vec.m_values;
    vec.m_length = 0;
    vec.m_values = nullptr;
    return *this;
};
```

The constructors are defined in the class .cpp file, and the assignment operators in the header file. A hopefully easy question for those with experience: are there problems in this code? I tried to write these based on things I've read on the internet and Stroustrup's addressing of it in the 4th edition, but somewhere I have done something seriously wrong.

I get two types of errors intermittently:

1. incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
2. Seg fault
   I have tried valgrind, but it has not helped yet.

Comment: Show the class definition. `m_length` should be an integral type, such as `size_t`, not a floating point. Otherwise you may get rounding errors in your array length which would be a disaster.

Comment: There's no other obvious error in the code you have posted so far, to get help with debugging it is best to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The assignment operators can be greatly improved by using [copy and swap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1734640/1505939) but the existing versions should work.

Comment: `int i=0` should be `size_t i = 0;` (at least!)

Comment: Many hours after my problem arose, it seems to have disappeared. In my varied extensive debugging efforts though, I don't actually know where/why :( Good tips on size_t and copy/swap though, thanks!

Comment: In the assignment operators, you need to check for self-assignment, otherwise `a = a;` is going to blow away your data before copying it. First statement should be `if (&vec == this) return *this;`